# Comparing user input to a variable in php

Tags: php

Hi i am new to using php and im still trying to find my way around it. I have a form where i want to update information in the database. I have a textbox where the user enters the id nd I want to compare the id the user puts in to the Id's in the database so as to update the information of that user. I have been searching around but cant find what im looking for.

Comment: what do you have so far? any familiarity with PHP/SQL? we need a starting point to answer your question. otherwise you have to make use of some tutorial first.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

suppose that you have the following formula in the file **formular.html** which have to send information to the file **receive.php**

```
<form action="receive.php" method="post">
   Name : <input type="text" name="user_id" />
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

According to the fact that the sending method of the formular is here **post**. here's how the **receive.php** could look like

```
<?php
    // receiving information
    $id = $_POST['user_id'];

    // connecting to database to retrive id to be compare
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("sampleDatabase",$link);

    // writing your query
    $query = "SELECT id FROM sampleTable WHERE 1;";

    // executing your query
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);*

    // fetching the result
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    // testing the similarity between information from the database and the one from the formular
    if($id == $row['id']) // make a decision
    else // make another decision

    // for dealing whit many line on the result use the following code
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       // make a stuff with $row
    } 

    // may be you could want to do a redirection if so the use the following header function

    header("Location: formular.html");
?>
```

Comment: Works fine but only if there's just one row in the table...

Comment: @Juhana to deal with many lines use the following code __while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){// make a stuff here with $row}__

Comment: Do you really think that querying ALL the records from the table is the wisest solution? Do you use this in production?

Comment: @bazmegakapa, look at the modify code now

Comment: @FOPALéonConstantin OK. Your code queries the DB for ALL the records in the database (this could be a lot!). Instead, you should query the database for the specific item with the ID. Database engines are designed to run queries, and get ONLY the data you need.